# Social sharing: Individual meta tags for different platforms, eg for optimised images

Tags: meta-tags, schema.org, share-open-graph

I would like to know if there is a way to use meta information such as `<meta property="og:image" content="image.jpg">`and `<meta name="twitter:image" content="tw-image.jpg">`

to rather have image links to correctly sized images depending on what social platform they are being shared to.

In other words

A person from Facebook shares a link to my webpage http://www.example.com/pagex/ and facebook shows the image source i have provided fb-image.jpg at a size of 1200px x 900px so it does not crop my image.

Another person goes to share the same url http://www.example.com/pagex/ on google plus, and google plus chooses the source image i have provided gplus-image.jpg at a size of 1080px x 1080px so it shows my full image.

Another one for pinterest and another for twitter and another for linkedin

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: From a structured data perspective, there would be a way to provide images in different resolutions. But it’s up to the consumers (like Facebook and Google Plus) to make use of this. -- Is your question whether these consumers support it, or how it can be marked up (no matter if it’s supported)?

Comment: I suppose my question would be, is there a way currently to force each social platform to only see the markup i know is going to work for them, so in my website i suppose i would want something like a conditional statement saying, if api.facebook.com then do this, else if api.pinterest.com then do something else. i have no idea if this would be possible, but if google analytics can distinguish between social signals from different providers then surely if a user is sharing from facebook or pinterest itself, then my head tag could conditionally show a specific element only.